# call function with different categories

Tags: python-3.x, function, nltk, apply

In the below code: the condition applied for the matching category is 'Recreation',-"**if joined in Recreation:**" . Like wise, i have a list of categories containing 'Recreation','Security','HealthCare', etc.

```
def match_bigrams(row,RC):
    categories = []

    for bigram in row.bigram:
        joined = ' '.join(list(bigram))
        if joined in RC:
            categories.append(joined)

    return categories

df['Recreation_Amenities'] = df.apply(match_bigrams(Recreation), axis=1)
```

Category List is:

```
category = [('Luxury Apartments', 'IN', 'Recreation_Ammenities'),
        ('CCTV', 'IN','Security'),
        ('Yoga', 'IN', 'HealthCare'),
        ('Jogging Tracks', 'IN', 'Recreation_Ammenities')]
Recreation = [e1 for (e1, rel, e2) in category if e2=='Recreation_Ammenities']
Security= [e1 for (e1, rel, e2) in category if e2=='Security']
HealthCare= [e1 for (e1, rel, e2) in category if e2=='HealthCare']
```

How do I call the same function by passing the category name as an argument here?
I tried passing category name:**if joined in RC:** but it's throwing a TypeError:

> TypeError: match_bigrams(Recreation) missing 1 required positional argument:RC

Comment: Please **edit your question** and show exactly how you "tried passing category name" to `match_bigrams()`, to get the `TypeError` you report.

Comment: I have edited the question, pls find the updated one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a way to pass one argument to your function, and end up with a new (temporary) function that takes one more argument. Here's a simple way to do it:

```
df['Recreation_Amenities'] = df.apply(lambda r: match_bigrams(r, Recreation), axis=1)
```

The `apply()` method will supply each row as the argument `r`.

In functional programming this is called "partial application", and there is a function `funtools.partial()` that you can use for the same purpose. It works best when the pre-supplied argument comes first:

```
from functools import partial

def match_bigrams(RC, row):
    ...

df['Recreation_Amenities'] = df.apply(partial(match_bigrams, Recreation), axis=1)
```

Here `Recreation` will be used as the first argument of `match_bigrams`, and `partial` will again return a one-argument function (whose argument will be supplied by `apply()`).